# kubectl get secrets display specific field

Tags: shell, kubernetes, kubectl

How to get only name field when we run kubectl get secrets? I want to get all the values under 'name' field. Is it possible?

For example:

when I run below command in Kube:

````
```
 $kubectl get secrets -n mynamespace
  NAME     TYPE               DATA   AGE
  my-cert  kubernetes.io/tls     2   10d

```
````

from above I want to see only NAME field, how can we extract that ?

Comment: You can try to extract it, maybe like `kubectl get secret my-cert -n mynamespace -o jsonpath="{.data.name}" | base64 --decode ; echo`… Does not necessarily work because I had to guess the path, which should start with `.data`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by `kubectl get secrets -A -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name`

EDIT:
another option would be to `kubectl get secrets -A -o name` but in this case the output is e.g. "secret/cluster-kubernetes.default.svc".

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following command:

```
kubectl get secrets -n default -o jsonpath='{.items[*]}' | jq -r '.metadata.name' | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `jsonpath` option of kubectl:

```
kubectl get secrets -o jsonpath="{.items[*].metadata.name}"
```

More details could be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too ,use `awk`

```
kubectl get secrets -n mynamespace --no-headers|awk '{print $1}'
```

`--no-headers` means don't print headers like `NAME     TYPE               DATA   AGE`.
`awk '{print $1}'` to print the first word which is the name of secret